# Is there a way to Create a .Jar file from 1 .Class file without a manifest file on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I have looked everywhere online And can only create a .jar file that doesn't open when clicking on it, im using the command
"jar cvf test.jar TopLevelWindow.class" This creates a jar file that can't open when I click on it, however if I just click the .class file after gaining it from visual studio code it does open. I have tried more than once with multiple methods none worked, I open the file in the same directory it was created, im using java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS from oracle, anyone know why this wont work?

Code is

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class TopLevelWindow {

    private static void createwindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Binary Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Binary Test",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createwindow();
    }
}
```

if curious

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the command you enter in order to run the JAR file. Also post from which directory do you issue the command as well as the directory that the JAR file is in. What is the package that class `TopLevelWindow` is in? What Java version are you using?  You say you can execute class `TopLevelWindow` by itself, i.e. when it is not in a JAR. Do you do that from the command line or from an IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Move into the same directory as your class and do

```
jar cfe top-level-window.jar TopLevelWindow TopLevelWindow.class
```

You can then do

```
java -jar top-level-window.jar
```

I would encourage proper packaging though - don't just use the default package.